How do I deploy a supabase function that uses deno's hash/mod module?
import { createHmac, createHash } from "https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/hash/mod.ts";

My supabase edge function cannot be deployed because of the deno module hash/mod not being found.
I tried to deploy a supabase function using supabase functions deploy and this is the detailed debug output that i got:
supabase functions deploy get-kraken-transactions --debug
Supabase CLI 1.190.0
Error: failed to load 'https://deno.land/std@0.180.0/hash/mod.ts': Module not found "https://deno.land/std@0.180.0/hash/mod.ts".
2024/09/25 16:40:37 Sent Header: Host [api.moby.localhost]
2024/09/25 16:40:37 Sent Header: User-Agent [Docker-Client/unknown-version (windows)]
2024/09/25 16:40:37 Send Done
2024/09/25 16:40:37 Recv First Byte
error running container: exit 1

I tried a lot of different versions of that specific deno hash module but sadly they all give me the same output. the deno cache and updating deno also did not change my result. I have to use docker to deploy an edge function on supabase so it could have to do with it no clue though. Also I use deno for other edge functions where i am not using that specific hash module and in those cases deno does not complain and i can successfully deploy my edge functions. So I believe this to be a very specific issue and I am curious if anyone has dealt with it before.

Where did you get that URL? That module has been deprecated for a long time, and the current supported alternative is at https://jsr.io/@std/crypto
